# How to align divs or li inside a table with a different td

Tags: html, css

I want to align the right li to the left li. is there a css technique that i can use for this one? like using ids to align it? im stuck pls help

[image]

Comment: Share your code. Add vertical-align: top in second column

Comment: Don't use `vertical-align` because this would imply you are using table layouts. And table layouts are a thing from the last century. Use flexbox for this. Or grid.

Comment: what i wanted was to put the dates beside the li of the items if i use vertical align top or flexbox it would only move everything to the first li

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are trying to do... need to see your code anyways, if you hard code info then you can use pseudo elements to align them correctly

```
<body>
  <ul>
    <div>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</li>
      <li>DATE 1 </li>
    </div>

    <div>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</li>
      <li>DATE 2</li>
    </div>

    <div>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</li>
      <li>DATE 3</li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</body>

div {
  display: flex;
}

li {
  margin: 0 20px;
  width: 25%
}
```